# C# Scaling нарисованного сверху PictureBox

Tags: c#, рисование

Здравствуйте, рисую квадратные зоны на PictureBox который масштабируется вот так:

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
  var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
  var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
  var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
  var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
  var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
  var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
  using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
  return newImage;
}
```

Нужно масштабировать их вместе с боксом, у меня наверное плохи дела с пропорциями

Comment: А можно спросить? Как это вы `ratio` получаете деля максимально допустимую высоту/ширину на ширину/высоту изображения? Уж если вам надо сохранять пропорции, то используйте `1.0` для `ratio`.

Comment: @Yami, метод не мой, но он работает проблема в том что мне нужно вместе с боксом изменять все что я на нем рисую